# How do I pre-load ShellPage during Activation in a WinUI 3 NavigationView Desktop project?

Tags: c#, loading, startup, navigationview, winui-3

I'd like to pre-load the `ShellPage` in a WinUI 3 (v1.1.5) Desktop application. That is, during `Activation` (called by

```c#
await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
```

in the `OnLaunched` handler of the `App` class), I'd like to make sure `ShellPage` is loaded before any of the navigation pages are displayed. I've changed the service configuration to include

```c#
    services.AddSingleton<ShellPage>();
    services.AddSingleton<ShellViewModel>();
```

in the constructor for the `App` class which should mean only one of each of `ShellPage` and `ShellViewModel` will be instantiated for the app run but the question is when are they fully provisioned?

The normal progression is that the `Activation` step first assigns `ShellPage` to `MainWindow.Content`, then navigates to `MainPage` (these are the names for the default project). Because `MainPage` is actually loaded into a `Frame` on `ShellPage`, it seems layout for `MainPage` happens before `ShellPage` layout is completed.

Any idea how I do this on initial startup? This is only an issue when the first `Page` is presented. After that, `ShellPage` is reused.

Comment: Assuming that you're working with **Template Studio**, it's hard to understand your question. The first navigation to the ``MainPage`` is done through by ``DefaultActivationHandler``. Do you want to change this?

Comment: You are correct, it is done by `DefaultActivationHandler`. I'm happy to let that continue but I thought that there might be a way to include a custom `ActivationHandler` that would allow me to load (whatever that might mean) `ShellPage` first, before the `DefaultActivationHandler`. Any ideas?

Comment: You can replace the ``DefaultAcitvationHandler`` and replace it with your ``CustomActivationHandler``. Can you share more details about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to make sure that everything in the `ShellPage` element tree (and possibly other `Page` trees, as well) is available to all subsequent `xxxPage` loads. But, in practical terms, it's only the landing page for the `App` that matters (everything else can be made a `Singleton` instance).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to instantiate all your pages first, and only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little clarification first, and then the answer I found to the issue.

Andrew's answer (above) is great for instantiating all of the `Pages` in the `NavigationView` at startup but the very first page loaded still would not have access to a fully loaded `ShellPage` in its constructor (and thus, a fully populated element tree). Andrew is right that the `NavigationViewItems` (`Pages`) don't persist by default, but the `ShellPage` does as it's part of the UI. Specifically, it is the content of the `MainWindow` and defines a `Frame` into which `NavigationViewItems` are loaded. Regardless of which `Page` is displayed, it's the same instance of the `ShellPage` people see.

The issue arises because of the order in which `Activation` (specifically, the `DefaultActivationHandler`) is done at `App` startup. When the `App` starts, it calls

```c#
await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
```

which does

```c#
    // Set the MainWindow Content.
    if (App.MainWindow.Content == null)
    {
        _shell = App.GetService<ShellPage>();
        App.MainWindow.Content = _shell ?? new Frame();
    }
```

and navigates to the first `Page` (loads the first `Page` into the `NavigationView.Frame` by calling `DefaultActivationHandler`) **before** finishing the loading of `ShellPage`. Thus, `ShellPage` is not fully loaded (`ShellPage.IsLoaded == false`) when `MainPage` is loaded.

To fully instantiate `ShellPage` before any of the `NavigationViewItem` `Pages` are loaded, simply change the loading sequence. First, defer the navigation to the first page (whichever you choose) by editing `HandleInternalAsync` in `DefaultActivationHandler.cs` to

```c#
    protected async override Task HandleInternalAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        //_navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(MainViewModel).FullName!, args.Arguments);

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Move the navigation to the `OnLoaded` handler in `ShellPage.xaml.cs`:

```c#
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TitleBarHelper.UpdateTitleBar(RequestedTheme);

        KeyboardAccelerators.Add(BuildKeyboardAccelerator(VirtualKey.Left, VirtualKeyModifiers.Menu));
        KeyboardAccelerators.Add(BuildKeyboardAccelerator(VirtualKey.GoBack));

        App.GetService<INavigationService>().NavigateTo(typeof(MainViewModel).FullName!);
    }
```

All `Pages` now receive a loaded `ShellPage` when navigated to, regardless of order.

Comment: Thanks your line of code here really helped.
App.GetService<INavigationService>().NavigateTo(typeof(MainViewModel).FullName!);

Answer (score 2):

By default, **TemplateStudio**'s navigation re-instantiates pages for every navigation. It doesn't use the `ServicesProvider`, so registering your pages as singleton won't help.

If you want to keep your page instances, you need to set `NavigationCacheMode="Required"` on your pages. This way, your pages will be cached even after you navigate away.

Still, your pages won't be instantiated until you navigate to them once at least. In order to instantiate all of your pages at the very beginning, you need to navigate through them at least once.

You can get all the `NavigationViewItem`s with a method like this.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> GetNavigationViewItems(IEnumerable<object> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        yield return item;

        foreach (var grandChild in GetNavigationViewItems(item.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>()))
        {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this in the `NavigationViewService`'s `Initialize` method.

```cs
[MemberNotNull(nameof(_navigationView))]
public void Initialize(NavigationView navigationView)
{
    _navigationView = navigationView;
    _navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    _navigationView.ItemInvoked += OnItemInvoked;

    IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> menuItems = 
    GetNavigationViewItems(_navigationView.MenuItems);

    foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        if (item.GetValue(NavigationHelper.NavigateToProperty) is string pageKey)
        {
            _navigationService.NavigateTo(pageKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, for this very helpful explanation. I hadn't realized that the `Singletons` wouldn't persist and that I should cache the `Pages` instead. I do vaguely remember reading something about that before, but it wasn't as clear to me then as your explanation is now. Please see below for what I meant about pre-loading `ShellPage`.